# Meaning of different icons in the SSMS Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have noticed that the Database symbol to the left of the Server name in the object explorer tends to differ without any obvious reason. Two servers have a database symbol with a Green arrow on them and another server has a database symbol with a blue question mark (?). I use windows authentication on all servers. What is interesting is that I have two virtual desktops open (all connected to the same servers, but only one VDesktop has the blue icon/symbol. the rest are Green with a white arrow on them).
I just noticed this and was curious if anyone knew what they meant?

Just curious, because the Blue Question Mark is on my production server. Just want to make sure its no cause for concern. Sorry if the answer is very obvious

[image: Object Explorer Symbology]

Comment: I actually was just looking at that and cant seem to find any issues. I have a feeling its something obscure using the built-in Virtual desktops on windows 10, but i cant find an answer that fits my scenario. Im logged in as the same user on each Vdesktop which is Sysadmin using windows authentication

Comment: The primary point is that SSMS is not able to use a WMI call to the corresponding SQL Server to verify the service is running. There is some network factor that is blocking that communication. It's not necessarily good or bad, it depends on context related to your environment.

Comment: lol Now they are all Green arrows. Weird. It seems it was able to make a WMI call after a bout 30 mins or so

Comment: There can be a lot of factors involved with WMI calls. I've seen where the calls are able to happen and it can reach its target, but the target is too busy to respond. I would assume the WMI calls are scheduled out, it would not seem likely to constantly stream that information into SSMS.